# tfs getting some dlls as read-only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using jenkins to build my solutions. I am getting the source code from tfs using the tfs jenkins plugin. It uses tf.exe get - recursive command. My problem is - I have a libraries folder with all the referenced dlls. I am not sure why buy some of these dlls are downloaded as read-only and some are not.

Does any one know why? Or has anyone faced this issue before?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using and are the writable DLLs the ones you have possibly rebuilt or referenced from your local GAC?

Comment: I am using version 2010. None of them are being built by me. I get them from a libraries folder in tfs, is there a way to get them not marked as read-only.